# Get composer window id when a composerView is fired in InboxSDK

Tags: inboxsdk

I am using [inboxSDK](https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs) to create a gmail google chrome extension.

I want to get the current composer window id *(the html id attribute)* when the composer view is opened.

Like this:

```
sdk.Compose.registerComposeViewHandler(function(composeView){
    var window_id = how?
    ...
```

**What did I think about?**

I thought about using **addbutton()** to add a button with a specified unique id.

Then use javascript to traverse up the DOM until the div with the composer class is found and fetch its id.

Then destroy the added button.

But I wonder if there is a simpler approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**composeView.getElement()** returns the element of the compose window.

So you can just do `composeView.getElement().id`